# CakePHP - testAction always creates a GET request

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to test a controller in CakePHP 1.3 that requires a POST request but testAction always generates a GET request. I've boiled it down to a simple example action that purely reports the request method using:

```
$this->RequestHandler->isPost()
```

Or

```
$this->RequestHandler->isGet()
```

The result is always GET, whether or not I set `'method' => 'post'` or send a data array.

Forms of testAction I've tried:

```
$this->testAction('/testing/requesttype', array('method' => 'post'));
$this->testAction('/testing/requesttype', array('data' => array('Post' => array('title' => 'test')), 'method' => 'post'));
$this->testAction('/testing/requesttype', array('data' => array('Post' => array('title' => 'test'))));
$this->testAction('/testing/requesttype', array('form' => array('test' => 'test'), 'data' => array('Post' => array('title' => 'test')), 'method' => 'post'));
```

All of the above produce a GET request. If this can't be done in CakePHP 1.3, what is the point of `'method => 'post'`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to a decent version? 2.4? That would solve the issue. There it definitely works. 1.3 is too old for most of us to give you a reliable answer..

Comment: Much as we'd love to we have looked into it and it is too big a job for us to take on right now

Comment: Aren't you using this test on an action with redirect?

Comment: No, as I said I've reduced this down to the simplest possible action. All it does is output `$this->RequestHandler->isPost()`

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way, it's dirty but works for me:

```
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';
    $result = $this->testAction($url,
        array(
            'form' => $data
            )
        );
```